# ]Combine 2 integers into 1 byte

Tags: java, byte

Hello I have 2 integer values and would like to combine them into one byte in java. How do I go about doing it?

```
public class HelloWorld{
public static void main(String []args){
System.out.println("Hello World");

        int value = 3;
        int value2 = 4;

        byte b1 = (byte) value; 

        byte b2 = (byte) value2; 


        byte b = (byte) ((b1 << 8) | (b2 & 0xFF));


        System.out.println("Binary is " + Integer.toBinaryString(b));
```

}
}

The outcome is 100. However, I would like to achieve 00110100.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that a byte has only 8 bits. If you shift a value by 8, you can only end with 0! After seeing the expected value, you should only shift by 4 bits (and mask with `0x0F`):

```
    byte b = (byte) ((b1 << 4) | (b2 & 0x0F));
```